# Why does this Scala list has all elements equal?

Tags: list, scala

I am trying to add elements to a list, but it always ends up having all the elements equal.
I add the elements in this block of code:

```
var slots = List[Calendar]()                    
while (dateTimeBegin.getTime().compareTo(dateTimeEnd.getTime()) == -1) {
  dateTimeBegin.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 50)
  slots = dateTimeBegin :: slots
  println(dateTimeBegin.getTime())
}
```

This `println` prints this:

```
//> Wed May 25 12:50:00 WEST 2016
//| Wed May 25 13:40:00 WEST 2016
//| Wed May 25 14:30:00 WEST 2016
//| Wed May 25 15:20:00 WEST 2016
//| Wed May 25 16:10:00 WEST 2016
```

When I try to print the list:

```
for (i <- 0 to slots.length - 1) {
    println(slots(i).getTime())
}
```

I get this output:

```
//> Wed May 25 16:10:00 WEST 2016
//| Wed May 25 16:10:00 WEST 2016
//| Wed May 25 16:10:00 WEST 2016
//| Wed May 25 16:10:00 WEST 2016
//| Wed May 25 16:10:00 WEST 2016
```

I tried to change the line `slots = dateTimeBegin :: slots` in various ways. I tried to change the `::` to `::=` , `::+` and a lot of different combinations but got never managed to get the right result.

Does anyone know what am I doing wrong?

Comment: try to use a more functional approach to avoid such problems (immutability)

Answer (score 4):

You are changing the value inside of dateTimeBegin in the loop. Think about it: you added five references to the *same variable* to the list, and then you wonder why they all have the same value ...

There is a reason they don't like mutable variables in scala ...